# Is there a .NET function to remove the first (and only the first) occurrence at the start of a string?

Tags: string

I was using the TrimStart function to do the following:

```
var example = "Savings:Save 20% on this stuff";
example = example.TrimStart("Savings:".ToCharArray());
```

I was expecting this to result in example having a value of "Save 20% on this stuff".

However, what I got was "e 20% on this stuff".

After reading the documentation on TrimStart I understand why, but now I'm left wondering if there is a function in .NET that does what I was trying to do in the first place?

Does anyone know of a function so I don't have to create my own and keep track of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think such a method exists but you can easily do it using `StartsWith` and `Substring`:

```
s = s.StartsWith(toRemove) ? s.Substring(toRemove.Length) : s;
```

You can even add it as an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string RemoveFromStart(this string s, string toRemove)
    {
        if (s == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        }

        if (toRemove == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("toRemove");
        }

        if (!s.StartsWith(toRemove))
        {
            return s;
        }

        return s.Substring(toRemove.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the extension.  I was trying to avoid writing my own code to do this, but I guess it's unavoidable.

Comment: I'd personally go with a conditional here: `return s.StartsWith(toRemove) ? s.Substring(toRemove.Length) : s;` But I know not everyone is a fan of the conditional operator :)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, clear and easy to verify correctness. Here's an horrifically evil alternative I've actually seen in production code (altered to fit the example): `example.Split(new[] {"Savings:"}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]`. I don't know what the original author was thinking...

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe there's anything which does this built into the framework. It's a somewhat unusual requirement, IMO.

Note that you should think carefully about whether you're trying to remove "the first occurrence" or remove the occurrence *at the start of the string*, if there is one. For example, think what you'd want to do with: "Hello. Savings: Save 20% on this stuff".

Comment: Good Point.. My intention was only at the start of the string, not actually the first occurence. But again, only the first time, not repeatedly.

Comment: @Joseph: In that case, Mark's answer should do you fine. I'll leave this one here to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that quite easily using a regular expression.

Remove the occurrence on the beginning of the string:

```
example = Regex.Replace(example, @"^Savings:", "");
```

Remove the first occurrence in the string:

```
example = Regex.Replace(example, @"(?<!Savings:.*)Savings:", "");
```

Comment: That doesn't look as simple to me as having a single extra (simple) method. In particular, it gets hairy as soon as you need to start removing something that has special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: @Jon, not at all, build the string using `Regex.Escape()` on the text to match and you're good.

Comment: Yes, but you've got to remember to do that... which I suspect many people wouldn't. I think Mark's solution is a lot simpler. More lines of code, but harder to get wrong.

Comment: @Jon, I agree with that. However, as with many other things (such as with LINQ's deferred execution), it's always a matter of knowing what you're doing to get it right.